# SSRS Report toolbar format appears stretched out

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, server, format, toolbar

SSRS Report is pushed to the server and in some cases it appears like this:

This is how we want it to appear:  [image]

and other cases looks like this: (not how we want it to appear) 
[image]

There isn't anything I'm setting that I am consciously aware of and I can't figure out how/where to change it.  Please advise.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add the server in question to the browsers compatibility - its a browser issue that causes the problem.